# Python Django - ForeignKey Class Choice for Model Field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I want to make it so that i can choose a foreignkey for a field model/class when creating and instance of a model. So something like this:

```
class Posts(models.Model):

    OwnerType = (
        (Accounts, 'User'),
        (Groups, 'Group'),
    )

    PostTypes = (
        ('Text', 'Text'),
        ('Photo', 'Photo'),
        ('Audio', 'Audio'),
        ('Video', 'Video'),
        ('Link', 'Link'),
    )

    owner = models.ForeignKey(OwnerType, default = 0, related_name = "post_owner")
    ownerid = models.IntegerField(blank = False, default = 0)
    owner_type = models.CharField(blank = False, default = '', max_length = 50)

    title = models.CharField(max_length = 500, default = '')
    contents = models.CharField(max_length = 500, default = '')
    attachment = models.CharField(max_length = 500, default = '')
    attachment_type = models.CharField(max_length = 500, default = '')
    link = models.CharField(max_length = 500, default = '')

    post_type = models.CharField(max_length = 20, choices = PostTypes, default = '')
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 20, default = 'public') # either public, private, or deleted

    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_active = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    @property
    def serialize(self):
        return {
            'p_id': self.id,

            'ownerid': self.ownerid,
            'owner': self.owner.serialize,
            'owner_type': self.owner_type,
            'title': self.title,
            'contents': self.contents,
            'attachment': self.attachment,
            'attachment_type': self.attachment_type,
            'link': self.link,
            'post_type': self.post_type,
            'status': self.status,
            'date_created': self.date_created,
            'last_active': self.last_active
        }

    class Meta:
        db_table = "posts"

# ---
```

but then i get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/RyanWaite/Desktop/epsity/webapp/models.py", line 320, in <module>
    class Posts(models.Model):
  File "/Users/RyanWaite/Desktop/epsity/webapp/models.py", line 335, in Posts
    owner = models.ForeignKey(OwnerType, default = 0, related_name = "post_owner")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 754, in __init__
    RECURSIVE_RELATIONSHIP_CONSTANT,
AssertionError: ForeignKey(((<class 'webapp.models.Accounts'>, u'User'), (<class 'webapp.models.Groups'>, u'Group'))) is invalid. First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string u'self'
```

Is that even possible? can i choose the model for a foreignkey when creating a new instance of a model? I have two type of models that can make posts: users and groups. a user can make a post or a group can make a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from documentation [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#methods-on-contenttype-instances)

> A normal ForeignKey can only “point to” one other model, which means that if the TaggedItem model used a ForeignKey it would have to choose **one and only one** model to store tags  for

You could use [GenericForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) which allows the relationship to be with any model

Comment: Thanks! i actually found my own way around this. i just used a type and type id fields then created a function that would return the model instance based on the given params. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So Here is my custom way around this:

i added a type and type_id fields, where type is a string of the Model Class.
then i created a function that would return the model instance based on the given params. for ex. :

```
def returnModelSerialized(type, id):
    if id == None:
        return 'error --- Missing id'

    if type == '' or Type == None:
        return 'error --- invalid type'

    if type == 'Account':
        obj = Accounts.objects.get(id = id)
        return obj.serialize

    if type == 'Group':
        obj = Groups.objects.get(id = id)
        return obj.serialize
```

so when i call a serialize property method, it'll look like this:

```
class Likes(models.Model):

OwnerType = (
    ('Account', 'Account'),
    ('Group', 'Group'),
)

ContentType = (
    ('Post', 'Post'),
    ('Comment', 'Comment'),
    ('Reply', 'Reply'),
    ('Group', 'Group'),
    ('Event', 'Event'),
)

ownerid = models.IntegerField(blank = False, default = 0)
owner_type = models.CharField(choices = OwnerType, blank = False, default = '', max_length = 50)

item_type = models.CharField(choices = ContentType, blank = False, default = '', max_length = 50)
item_id = models.IntegerField(blank = False, default = 0)

date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
last_active = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

@property
def serialize(self):
    return {
        'like_id': self.id,

        'ownerid': self.ownerid,
        'owner': returnModelSerialized( self.owner_type , self.ownerid ),
        'owner_type': self.owner_type,
        'item_type': self.item_type.serialize,
        'item_id': self.item_id,
        'date_created': self.date_created,
        'last_active': self.last_active
    }

class Meta:
    db_table = "likes"
```